# jQuery Modal Window Positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I cannot get this modal dialog to work property.

Problem is that in a browser will set at the top of the page. So if a user is scrolled to the bottom of a page, it will not show the black background, just the modal window.

Also if the window is smaller than a particular height, say 200px, you cannot see the dialog.

I would like it to set the dialog as fixed whereever the user is and show the dialog in the middle of the screen, regardless of their scroll position in the page.

See [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/ofoqu4/6/edit) Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.modal-mask should have

```
  position: fixed;
```

and you should get the .modal-window's outerWidth and outerHeight to include the padding.
Also, the left and top positions should be computed on click so that they are accurate even when the window changes dimensions.
http://jsfiddle.net/VirusZ/XqAFy/

Answer (score 0):

To get a full background blackout set the height of .modal-mask to $(window).height() instead of 100%.